# Why isn't my recursive method base case not returning a Boolean as it should be?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, maze

I have written a method that solves a given text editor maze through stacks and recursion, and it solves mazes. However, my issue is that when the maze given is unsolvable as in it is literally impossible to be solved because of the walls of the maze, it's almost as if my base case is being skipped over and not returning false. Here is the code

```
 private boolean findPath(MazeLocation cur, MazeLocation finish) {
        int row = cur.row;
        int col = cur.col;
        mazeToSolve.setChar(row, col, 'o');
        fileWriter.println("\n"+mazeToSolve.toString());
        char strX = 'X';
        char strH = 'H';

        // First ,we need to scan the 4 directions around current location to see where to go
        MazeLocation up = new MazeLocation(row-1, col);
        MazeLocation down = new MazeLocation(row+1, col);
        MazeLocation right = new MazeLocation(row, col+1);
        MazeLocation left = new MazeLocation(row, col-1);

        // BASE CASE - WHEN WE'VE REACHED FINISH COORDINATES
        if(cur.row == finish.row && cur.col == finish.col){
            return true;
        }
        // SECOND BASE CASE - IF MAZE ISNT SOLVABLE
        if (path.isEmpty() == true){ // if the path is empty, then there is no solution.
            return false;
        }

        // Check if we can go up
        if(up.getRow() >= 0){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(up.getRow(), up.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = up.getRow();
                col = up.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                return findPath(newCur, finish);
            }
        }

        // Check if we can go down
        if(down.getRow() < mazeToSolve.getRows()){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(down.getRow(), down.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = down.getRow();
                col = down.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                return findPath(newCur, finish);
            }
        }

        // Check if we can go right
        if(right.getCol() < mazeToSolve.getCols()){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(right.getRow(), right.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = right.getRow();
                col = right.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                return findPath(newCur, finish);
            }
        }

        // Check if we can go left
        if(left.getCol() >= 0){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(left.getRow(), left.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = left.getRow();
                col = left.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                return findPath(newCur, finish);
            }
        }

         // If we cant do any of the above then we need to backtrack by popping the top of stack
         // and leaving X's until we can move up, down, left, or right again.
         MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
         path.pop(); // popping the cur where we are putting the x
         mazeToSolve.setChar(row, col, 'x'); // putting the x
         return findPath(path.top(), finish); // now we need to return to the position where the stack is NOW after the pop
    }
```

As you can see, there are two base cases. One returns true - the maze is solved. And the other returns false - the maze is unsolvable. The code for my isEmpty() method is as such:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(head == null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It returns false by checking if the stack is empty. For example, if the maze runner runs into a wall and turns around it will leave an x in the text editor like so:

```
 0123456
0HHHHHHH
1ooooxxH
2HHHoHxH
3H  oHxH
4H HoHHH
5H Hoooo
6HHHHHHH
```

The maze starts at 6,5; and ends at 0,1. This is solvable. The x's represent a failed route, the o's represent the path from start to finish.

In this next example maze, it is impossible to finish when the code would start at 7,6.

```
HHHHHHH
      H
HHH H H
H   H H
H HHHHH
H H    
HHHHHHH
```

It would attempt to move left twice, leaving x's, then the stack would pop until there is no stack and the top of the stack is pointing towards null. But my base case code is being skipped over, it SHOULD BE testing if the stack is empty before trying to pop the empty stack, and if it is, then returning false. But it isn't. Any help please?

Comment: It seems this doesn’t compile since ‘path’ is not declared

Comment: Start with (7,6) is there any position on the maze?

Comment: It does compile, path is a Stack object declared in another method. and what do you mean Eklavya?

Comment: Are you using a specific lib for your project ?

Comment: No there is nothing special @bdzzaid , there must be something going wrong with the function thats making it skip over returning false for isEmpty(). I've tested isEmpty() separately and it works.

Comment: Can you share me the class associated to these two Object : mazeToSolve and path (LinkedList ?) please

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets try to understand the problem statement first. We are trying to find a possible path from source to target using depth first approach here.

There is one major flaw in the algorithm which is around the lines

```
        // Check if we can go up
        if(up.getRow() >= 0){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(up.getRow(), up.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = up.getRow();
                col = up.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                return findPath(newCur, finish);
            }
        }

        // Check if we can go down
        if(down.getRow() < mazeToSolve.getRows()){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(down.getRow(), down.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = down.getRow();
                col = down.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                return findPath(newCur, finish);
            }
        }
```

consider we are currently at point (2,2) and have an option to move in either of the 4 directions i.e (1,2) , (3,2) , (1,3) , (2,1).

As per your logic. we move in up direction first (1,2)

There could be 2 possibilities.

1. You find a path from this point (returns true)
2. You don't find a path and want to continue search to other three options. (returns false)

Your code currently won't explore further options if the path leads to a failure
due to the return statement

```
return findPath(newCur, finish);
```

This issue boils down to premature exit from the method before all operations are finished.

the following stack cleanup must be called before any return statement from the method which is currently called in only one of the scenarios

```
// If we cant do any of the above then we need to backtrack by popping the top of stack
// and leaving X's until we can move up, down, left, or right again.

path.pop(); // popping the cur where we are putting the x
```

I still did not understand the usage of explicit stack here completely. as recursion solves the similar problem which you are trying to solve using a stack.However,
I would like to suggest improvements around the following lines.

```
// Check if we can go up
        if(up.getRow() >= 0){
            if(mazeToSolve.getChar(up.getRow(), up.getCol()) == ' '){
                row = up.getRow();
                col = up.getCol();
                MazeLocation newCur = new MazeLocation(row, col);
                path.push(newCur);
                boolean val =  findPath(newCur, finish);
                if(val){
                  path.pop();
                  return true;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, however it didn't help me. Again, here's how my code works: Maze begins, maze searches for a path in every direction and it follows the available open path until a dead end OR it reaches the end point of the maze. It does this using a stack, every coordinate is added to the stack. If it reaches a dead end, it pops the top of the stack until another path is available. My problem is that if a maze is literally impossible to complete, as in the path is walled in on 4 sides and there is no where to go, my method is not returning 'false' meaning it cant find a solution.

Comment: My mazerunner method works on every maze that has a possible solution, the algorithm is not broken. If there is no real solution, my method gives me an Empty Stack Exception, because it's attempting to delete the top of an empty stack.

Comment: Also, your fixed code your answer includes would stop any recursion after the first move upwards